# What is left over when water and sodium hypochorate decompose, i.e. household bleach?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

I am having some confusion in understanding the decompostion of household bleach. One website says bleach decomposes to  salt and sodium chlorate, simple enough.

Orther wedsites say bleach decomposes to salt and nothing else. I called Clorox customer service and their vote is it converts to salt only. I have 3 votes for salt only and 2 votes for salt and sodium chlorate thus far.

Comment: @Nilay Ghosh.  Yes my motivation for my question was a safely concern as you guessed. Thank you for the link. It is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

It depends on temperature. At higher temperatures, hypochlorite has tendency to disproportionate: $$\ce{3 ClO- -> 2 Cl- + ClO3-}$$ Otherwise it mostly releases atomic oxygen : $$\ce{ClO- -> Cl- + O}$$

In reality, it would be combination of both in various ratio, depending on relative reaction rates,  all ending as mixture of sodium hydroxide, carbonate, chloride and chlorate.